# Confirm Dialog doesn't work right with layoutUnit

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

how to solve this problem, I am using the confimDialog and layoutunit with primefaces. I've used the appendToBody, but does not work properly.
When I did not use the layoutunit works correctly.
I would like to use the appendToBody and my bean access the controller. When I use this property it does not access my bean

this is my template:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="false" footer="© 2013 Nota Fiscal Eletrônica v. #{UsuarioLogadoControl.versao }" >
        <h:form id="formCorpo">
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
            <p:growl autoUpdate="true" />
            <div class="main">
                <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />
                <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Aguarde..." draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" appendToBody="true" modal="true">
                    <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
                </p:dialog>
                <ui:insert name="corpo" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
```

this is my confirmDialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="dialogConfirmaNotaFiscal" widgetVar="confirmacao" message="A NOTA FISCAL não terá valor fiscal caso não seja confirmada após inclusão" header="Atenção ao Incluir" showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" severity="alert">
            <p:commandButton value="OK" update="msg" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" action="#{NotaFiscalControl.incluir}" ajax="false" rendered="#{!NotaFiscalControl.substituicao}"  />
            <p:commandButton value="OK" update="msg" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" action="#{NotaFiscalControl.substituir}" ajax="false" rendered="#{NotaFiscalControl.substituicao}" />
            <p:commandButton value="CANCELAR" onclick="confirmacao.hide()" type="button" />
       </p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confirmDialog needs to be in a seperate form. Plus, your EL expression is not right.

```
"#{NotaFiscalControl.incluir}"
```

The referenced managed bean in an EL expression , by default always starts with a lower case character, as this  :

```
"#{notaFiscalControl.incluir}"
```

Did you explicitly name your Managed Bean NotaFiscalControl as `@ManagedBean(name = "NotaFiscalControl")` ? If not, you have to start with a lower case in your EL expression.

Comment: Thanks about your response. Yes, so much that he has worked without component: **layoutunit** the primefaces

Comment: Did you solve it ? What version of Primefaces are you on ? You can make the confirmDialog global with `global="true"`. Primefaces 4.0 supports it. Where is your dialog ? Inside or outside layout element ?

Comment: My dialog is in the child page